# Epson printer connect fails status ERR_CONN

Tags: android, printing, epson

I have an Epson printer and I used epos2_printer (sample project) code given with SDK to integrate with my app. I have copied the same code but it never seems to work!

However, the same works when I connect the sample project to my printer.

```
private boolean runPrintReceiptSequence() {
    if (!initializeObject()) {
        return false;
    }

    if (!createReceiptData()) {
        finalizeObject();
        return false;
    }

    if (!printData()) {
        finalizeObject();
        return false;
    }

    return true;
}

private boolean initializeObject() {
    try {

        final SpnModelsItem spnModel = new SpnModelsItem("TM-T82 Series", Printer.TM_T82);
        final SpnModelsItem spnLang = new SpnModelsItem("ANK", Printer.MODEL_ANK);

        mPrinter = new Printer(spnModel.getModelConstant(), 
                                spnLang.getModelConstant(), this);
    }
    catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e("Printer", e.toString());
        return false;
    }

    mPrinter.setReceiveEventListener(this);


    return true;
}

private boolean createReceiptData() {
    String method = "";
    Bitmap logoData = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.logo_saltnpepper);
    StringBuilder textData = new StringBuilder();
    final int barcodeWidth = 2;
    final int barcodeHeight = 100;
    Date currentDate = new Date();
    info.saltnpepper.ordersmart2.MenuItem currItem = null;

    double price = 0;
    double total = 0;
    int totalQty =0;

    if (mPrinter == null) {
        return false;
    }

    try {
        method = "addTextAlign";
        mPrinter.addTextAlign(Printer.ALIGN_CENTER);

        method = "addImage";
        mPrinter.addImage(logoData, 0, 0,
                          logoData.getWidth(),
                          logoData.getHeight(),
                          Printer.COLOR_1,
                          Printer.MODE_MONO,
                          Printer.HALFTONE_DITHER,
                          Printer.PARAM_DEFAULT,
                          Printer.COMPRESS_AUTO);

        method = "addFeedLine";
        mPrinter.addFeedLine(1);
        textData.append("SALT-N-PEPPER\n");
        //textData.append("STORE DIRECTOR â€“ John Smith\n");
        textData.append("\n");
        textData.append((new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yy HH:mm:ss")).format(currentDate).toString() + "\n");
        //textData.append("ST# 21 OP# 001 TE# 01 TR# 747\n");
        textData.append("------------------------------\n");
        method = "addText";
        mPrinter.addText(textData.toString());
        textData.delete(0, textData.length());
        if(alFinalOrder != null)
        {
            for(int i=0; i < alFinalOrder.size(); i++)
            {
                currItem = alFinalOrder.get(i);
                textData.append(currItem.getName()+"  "+currItem.getQty()+"  "+currItem.getPrice()+"\n");

                //calculate total quantity
                totalQty = totalQty + currItem.getQty();

                //calculate price
                double dPrice = currItem.getQty()*Double.parseDouble(currItem.getPrice().substring(1));
                total = total + dPrice;
                total = Math.round(total*100.0)/100.0;

            }
        }
        textData.append("------------------------------\n");
        method = "addText";
        mPrinter.addText(textData.toString());
        textData.delete(0, textData.length());

        textData.append("TOTAL                   "+"\n");
        textData.append("TAX                     "+"\n");
        method = "addText";
        mPrinter.addText(textData.toString());
        textData.delete(0, textData.length());
```

mPrinter.addFeedLine(2);

```
        method = "addBarcode";
        mPrinter.addBarcode("01209457",
                            Printer.BARCODE_CODE39,
                            Printer.HRI_BELOW,
                            Printer.FONT_A,
                            barcodeWidth,
                            barcodeHeight);

        method = "addCut";
        mPrinter.addCut(Printer.CUT_FEED);
    }
    catch (Exception e) {
        //ShowMsg.showException(e, method, mContext);
        return false;
    }

    textData = null;

    return true;
}

private boolean printData() {
    if (mPrinter == null) {
        return false;
    }

    if (!connectPrinter()) {
        return false;
    }

    PrinterStatusInfo status = mPrinter.getStatus();

    dispPrinterWarnings(status);

    if (!isPrintable(status)) {
        Log.e("Printer", "Is not printable");
        try {
            mPrinter.disconnect();
        }
        catch (Exception ex) {
            // Do nothing
        }
        return false;
    }

    try {
        mPrinter.sendData(Printer.PARAM_DEFAULT);
    }
    catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e("Printer", e.getMessage());
        try {
            mPrinter.disconnect();
        }
        catch (Exception ex) {
            // Do nothing
        }
        return false;
    }

    return true;
}

private boolean connectPrinter() {
    boolean isBeginTransaction = false;

    if (mPrinter == null) {
        return false;
    }

    try {
        mPrinter.connect("TCP:"+mIP, Printer.PARAM_DEFAULT);
    }
    catch (Epos2Exception e) {
        //ShowMsg.showException(e, "connect", this);
        if(e.getErrorStatus() == Epos2Exception.ERR_CONNECT)
        {
            Log.e("testing", "error connect");
        }
        if(e.getErrorStatus() == Epos2Exception.ERR_ALREADY_OPENED)
        {
            Log.e("testing", "already open");
        }
        if(e.getErrorStatus() == Epos2Exception.ERR_ALREADY_USED)
        {
            Log.e("testing", "already used");
        }
        if(e.getErrorStatus() == Epos2Exception.ERR_BOX_CLIENT_OVER)
        {
            Log.e("testing", "box client over");
        }
        if(e.getErrorStatus() == Epos2Exception.ERR_BOX_COUNT_OVER)
        {
            Log.e("testing", "count over");
        }
        if(e.getErrorStatus() == Epos2Exception.ERR_DISCONNECT)
        {
            Log.e("testing", "disconnect");
        }
        if(e.getErrorStatus() == Epos2Exception.ERR_FAILURE)
        {
            Log.e("testing", "failure");
        }
        if(e.getErrorStatus() == Epos2Exception.ERR_ILLEGAL)
        {
            Log.e("testing", "illegal");
        }
        if(e.getErrorStatus() == Epos2Exception.ERR_IN_USE)
        {
            Log.e("testing", "in use");
        }
        if(e.getErrorStatus() == Epos2Exception.ERR_MEMORY)
        {
            Log.e("testing", "memory");
        }
        return false;
    }

    try {
        mPrinter.beginTransaction();
        isBeginTransaction = true;
    }
    catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e("Printer", e.toString ());
    }

    if (isBeginTransaction == false) {
        try {
            mPrinter.disconnect();
        }
        catch (Epos2Exception e) {
            // Do nothing
            return false;
        }
    }

    return true;
}
```

It always gives me exception ERR_CONNECT on printer.connect inside connectprinter function.

What am I doing wrong?

This code works fine with the sample app.
P.S: I have tried to connect this app before connecting the sample app to check if the sample app holds the connection and does not allow other apps to connect but that is not the case. Epson help is unable to provide any further help.

My AndroidManifest.xml

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="xyz"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0" >

<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="21"
    android:targetSdkVersion="21" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/icon"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity android:name=".MenuActivity" >
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".SaltnPepperActivity"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_saltn_pepper" >
    </activity>
            <activity
        android:name=".FinalOrder"
         ></activity>
                <activity
        android:name=".ZinVietActivity"
         >
    </activity>
     <activity
        android:name="com.epson.epos2_printer.DiscoverActivity"
         ></activity>

</application>
```

Comment: what mode are you using usb otg etc

Comment: If you are getting connection error make sure you are using proper model name and other constants. If you are using micro usb make sure you get some tcp path like tcp://../../usb1  This info can be obtain by discoverabilty as defined in SDK doc and sample application

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Looks like you don't have the proper permissions in your manifest. Try putting these in your project under the `manifest` tag:

`<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH"/>`

`<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH_ADMIN"/>`

`<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>`

`<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>`

They also have the

`<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"/>`

permission but I'm not sure you need it. I think the essentials are Bluetooth and Internet permissions.

Comment: ok!! will try it onsite tomorrow..but just curious..do i need the permissions even when my printer is connected to the network?

Comment: I believe you would need the internet permission for that. Not 100%, but give it a shot, if that doesn't work we will try something else.

Comment: Oh wow... I was bumping my head for an hour then added the permissions and, boom! works. thx

Answer (score 2):

As I suspect there seems to be an error in connect printer method. I have used this SDK once so better follow the documentation properly (means don't skip steps). Make sure you have defined permission as mentioned in the SDK.

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH_ADMIN"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"/>


<activity android:name=".MainActivity" android:label="@string/app_title"  android:screenOrientation="portrait">
<intent-filter>
<action android:name="android.hardware.usb.action.USB_DEVICE_ATTACHED"/>
<action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
<category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
</intent-filter>
<meta-data android:name="android.hardware.usb.action.USB_DEVICE_ATTACHED" android:resource="@xml/device_filter"/>
```

As I see you haven't mentioned what type of connection you are making thus, in that case, there must be problem in selecting **target**

Check out the function from SDK:

> Public void connect(String target, int timeout) throws Epos2Exception;

[image]

You might be using wrong target parameter.

Note: if you are using USB or any other mode make sure run discoverability service as per the docs.

```
 Discovery.start(this, mFilterOption, mDiscoveryListener);
```

It will return you the required target name. And I am sure no connection failure will occur. Good Luck \o

Comment: Thanks, man! Once I did discover, I was able to connect and print easily. :-)

Answer (score 1):

`Status ERR_CONN` is basically shows if device cannot be reached or `connection failing` with device. It can be `USB, LAN/NETWORK, Bluetooth` Connection failure status.

If you are trying to connect printer with Bluetooth then you must write below permissions:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH_ADMIN"/>
```

If you are using LAN for network printers then

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
```

For USB Printer Connection Use:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"/>
```

As you are using **EPOS2 Sample Project**, remember to import Jar file "EPOS2.jar". [Click here to download the file.](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0Bz85KnRe2hv6MnA3eUFuZWo5YVU/view?usp=sharing)